# Accessing HDFS from Eclipse outside Hadoop cluster

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to read some files available on HDFS from a Java program. I have created a mavenized project with Eclipse, added as dependecies hadoop-core 1.2.1, hadoop-common 2.3.0 and hadoop-client 2.3.0. However, whenever I try to get a FileSystem object (also on the first line of the program):

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
```

It crashes with execption:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:215)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2284)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2294)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2311)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:90)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2350)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2332)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:369)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:168)

Any idea on how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Problem solved. Don't know why but the dependency on hadoop-client 2.3.0 was the problem, after removing it the code worked.